# run 10 sql scripts in parallel in oracle

Tags: shell, unix, sed, plsql

Unix shell script run every 10 SQL scripts in parallel in oracle DB

I have file.txt :-
script1.sql
script2.sql
.
.
.
script100.sql

I want to pickup 10 script and run in oracle DB parallelly then wait till those complete and run next 10 and so on till all scripts completed.

Comment: What is in the SQL scripts? Could it be built in PL/SQL? The process could then easily be built to run in parallel using `DBMS_SCHEDULER`

Comment: There is one insert statements in each  sql fiile

Comment: Maybe run each script with  `nohup <command> &`?

Comment: i want logic that pickup 10 scripts to run parallelly and then next lot

Comment: Try typing [gnu-parallel] into StackOverflow search box.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
parallel -j10 sql ora://user:pass@server/db '<' ::: *sql
```

or:

```
parallel -j10 sql ora://user:pass@server/db '<' :::: file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have gnu parallel installed but awk is available, then an awk script like this could work:

```
function workOnBufferedLines(maxprint){
    cmd = ""
    for(i=1; i<= maxprint; i++){
        # instead of echo use your sql script executor
        cmd= cmd "echo " buffer[i % MAX] " &\n"
    }
    
    # wait waits for all background jobs to finish
    cmd = cmd "wait\n"

    system(cmd)
}

# set the MAX to the number of lines to buffer
BEGIN{ MAX=10 }

# default rule: append to buffer
{ buffer[NR % MAX] = $0 }

# every MAX line:
NR % MAX == 0 { workOnBufferedLines(MAX) }

# at the file end: work on remaining lines in buffer
END{ workOnBufferedLines(NR%MAX) }
```

Save the snippet as script.awk and run it like

```
awk -f script.awk file.txt
```

Instead of `echo` in line 5 use your sql interpreter (e.g. sqlplus).

The idea is to build a sequence of shell commands each ending with `&` to run them as background jobs and use the `wait` command to wait for all jobs to finish before going on.

Comment: Thanks Lars, it worked well ,..... I was wondering if we can have logic that will run 10 script at any given point of time .. right now whats happening is 10 scripts started to run and complete one by one till the time 10th script is completed it does not go for next lot of 10 scripts ... I want as 1 script completed new should start running.....

Comment: @sam I fear the awk based solution is not able to do that. Do you have `make` available? What you want might be possible with `make`.

Can you install `parallel`? Then follow Oles answer.